# Can Resharper skip async/await keywords?

Tags: c#, resharper, async-ctp

I am trying to see how new C# 5.0 asynchronous ([CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/async)) features will work. I also use ReSharper. But because it is only a CTP, ReSharper [doesn't support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-196518#tab=Comments) new keywords (*async*/*await*) and highlights them as errors.

This is how it looks (code from CTP samples)

[image: ReSharper failed to understand async await keywords]

**Is it possible to make ReSharper just skip these words for now?**

UPDATE

I tried Early Access Program ReSharper build 6.0.2151.53 (10 May 2011) with no luck. The issue is still there so if you want it to be resolved give your vote [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-196518?projectKey=RSRP) (following Peter's answer).

Comment: Most of the suggestions I see from ReSharper come with an option to place a comment around the found issue to keep ReSharper from complaining. Maybe this is true for yours, too? Try `Alt`+`Enter` and see what options came up in the context menu.

Comment: @Uwe Keim I have put a screenshot. It seems there is no option for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Early Release of Resharper 6.1](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program) now supports the async CTP.

If you can, it'd probably be worth waiting for the proper release version though.

Answer (score 7):

Async is a new language syntax that is not yet RTM, so Resharper has yet to support it. If you feel this is important, the issue is being tracked b Jetbrains and you can vote for it here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-196518?projectKey=RSRP

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Following your advice I have just voted there

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from the comments made on the issue you mentioned yourself, 5.1.3 has no support for them yet and from what I understand there are no plans to release a fix for this any time soon.

But ReSharper 6 is just around the corner and it's already available through the Early Access Program. Have you tried that? I cannot try it myself right now, but I would assume it might already support the new keywords.

Comment: To expand on this answer you can find the MEAP nightly builds at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds .

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try and let you know.